# how to group by multiple columns and aggregate the last column in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Not sure if I am just having a brain fart because this problem seems VERY simple:

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+
| user_id  | country  | country_probability |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 10000022 | France   | 0.126396313         |
| 10000022 | Italy    | 0.343407512         |
| 10000022 | England  | 0.161236539         |
| 10000044 | China    | 0.061884698         |
| 10000044 | S. Korea | 0.043251887         |
| 10000044 | Japan    | 0.65095371          |
| 10000046 | USA      | 0.215771168         |
| 10000046 | Canada   | 0.214556068         |
| 10000046 | Mexico   | 0.081350066         |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

In Redshift, how do I group this so that my output is: unique user_id, country that is the max probability, and the probability of that country for that user_id?

Which would be:

```
+----------+---------+---------------------+
| user_id  | country | country_probability |
+----------+---------+---------------------+
| 10000022 | Italy   | 0.343407512         |
| 10000044 | Japan   | 0.65095371          |
| 10000046 | USA     | 0.215771168         |
+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

Thank you and sorry if this is a duplicate post... I tried searching but wasn't able to find much. The grouping function seems to work different in Redshift vs MySQL...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
select user_id, country, country_probability
from your_table
where (user_id, country_probability) in 
      (select user_id, max(country_probability)
       from test
       group by user_id
      )
```

**[EDIT: yet another option, using analytic RANK function]**

```
select user_id, country, country_probability
from (select user_id, country, 
        country_probability,
        rank() over (partition by user_id order by country_probability desc) rnk
        from your_table
     )
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: thank you this works. is this really the best way to do it though? i also solved this in a similar way, but it seems unnecessarily difficult (doing subqueries) just to get a simply output like this...

Comment: The other option is tagging the rows with an analytic function but I don't even know if those are available to you. That's a pretty typical query for this request and you'll find it all over SO.

Comment: I guess you could try with analytic functions (just as @shawnt00 said), such as RANK. I edited my answer, give it a try.

Comment: thanks for the responses Littlefoot. I also solved it using the rank function... i guess i just wanted to confirm that i wasnt overcomplicating this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to compare the performance of Littlefoot's methods with:

```
select distinct user_id,
       first_value(country) over (partition by user_id order by country_probability desc),
       min(country_probability) over (partition by user_id)
from t;
```

I am not generally a fan of using `select distinct` for aggregation, but Redshift only supports `first_value()` as a window function.